# Trouble loading new scene with VRTK and Unity SceneManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vrtk, scene-manager

I’m trying to load a new scene in Unity (5.6.1) with VRTK but having troubles. I’ve tried SceneManager.loadscene (both single and additive modes) which put my VRTK camera in the next scene in the floor and not usable by VRTK. SteamVR_LoadScene options crash unity. I’ve tried checking persist on load in the VRTK manager and the UnloadSDKManager method before LoadScene but nothing seems to be working. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SteamVR_Loadscene was not compatible with VRTK version 3.1.0 or below. I was able to solve by updating my VRTK version to the latest 3.2.0.